# Does Rith, the Awakener count only permanents I own?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Does [Rith, the Awakener](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rith%2C%20the%20Awakener) count only permanents I own, or should I count my opponents permanents too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The relevant part of Rith's ability says "for each permanent of that color", without any further qualification on what sorts of things get counted. Therefore, you count each thing that is a permanent of that color. Whether you own the permanent or someone else does, that has no effect on whether it is a permanent of that color; in other words, permanents owned by all players should be counted.

Similarly, it doesn't matter who controls the permanent, what kind of permanent it is, how long it's been on the battlefield, whether it's a card or a token, whether it's transformed or flipped, etc.